# Ignore/Ovewrite .pigbootup configurations

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have a `.pigbootup` file configured which configures `SET DEFAULT_PARALLEL` for all the pig jobs. The script on which I am working on doesn't require that many reducers and I don't want to use that configuration. How can I overwrite/ignore the configuration which are given in this file?

Comment: Have you tried `set default_parallel x` in your script to override the value?

Comment: I tried that, but the my configured value in the script doesn't overwrite that value. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this a great way to ignore the `.pigbootup` file completely. But, if you want to overwrite the property values and still use the existing configurations, then I don't think this is a great idea. But, my case worked just fine.

```
pig -Dpig.load.default.statements=/tmp/.non-existent-pigboot -f test.pig
```

Reference - https://hadoopified.wordpress.com/2013/02/06/pig-specify-a-default-script/